# Correction of the mouseout and mouse over in relation to table

Tags: javascript, jquery

Goal:
The row should have a different background color if the mouse's icon is inside of table's rows. When the icone is outside of the row, the background of the row should be turned back into default.

Problem:
I can't make the sourcode in jQuery to be working properly.

I would like to use jQuery only.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uCFQ4/6/)

---

```
    <TABLE id="dataTable" width="350px" border="1">
        <TR class="row_overr">
            <TD>4</TD>
            <TD>1</TD>
            <TD>22</TD>
            <TD></TD>            
        </TR>
         <TR class="row_overr">
            <TD>4</TD>
            <TD>1</TD>
            <TD>22</TD>
            <TD></TD>            
        </TR>       
         <TR>
            <TD>4</TD>
            <TD>1</TD>
            <TD>22</TD>
            <TD></TD>            
        </TR>       
    </TABLE>




$(document).ready(function(){

    /*
    $('tr').live('mouseover', function() {
  $(this).addClass('row_over');
});


        $('tr').live('mouseout', function() {
  $(this).addClass('row_overr');
});

    */




    $('tr').mouseover(function()
    {
        $(this).addClass('row_over');
    });


        $('tr').mouseout(function()
    {
        $(this).addClass('row_overr');
    });


});






.row_over
{
    background: #AA1133;
}

.row_overr
{
    background: #FFFFFF;
}
```

Comment: in your fiddle you have selected mootools...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need jQuery/javascript for this at all.

Plain old [CSS works in all modern browsers](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/contents.html#t16):

```
#dataTable tr:hover {
    background: #AA1133;
}
```

[See the fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/uCFQ4/10/)

Answer (score 1):

you can use [`jquery hover`](http://api.jquery.com/hover/)

```
$("table tr").hover(
function(){ //handles the mouseenter
    $(this).removeClass('row_overr');
    $(this).addClass('row_over');
},
 function(){ //handles the mouseleave                  
     $(this).addClass('row_overr');
     $(this).removeClass('row_over');

});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/3nigma/uCFQ4/7/)

**Update**

as Brock Adams mentioned it can be simplified by taking advantage of jquery chaining

```
$("table tr").hover(function(){
$(this).removeClass('row_overr').addClass('row_over');
},
function(){           
$(this).addClass('row_overr').removeClass('row_over');

});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/3nigma/uCFQ4/11/)

Comment: +1, but note that you can simplify each function like so:  `$(this).addClass ('row_overr').removeClass ('row_over');`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('tr').mouseover(function()
    {
        $(this).addClass('row_over');
    });


    $('tr').mouseout(function()
    {
        $(this).addClass('row_overr');
    });


});






.row_over
{
    background: #AA1133;
}

.row_overr
{
    background: #FFFFFF !important;
}
```